Figuring out a Json format for the background to change colour for multiple values




I am wanting to format a column so it can automatically recognize different phrases and change the background of that cell to the same color.
So for example I may have 5 rows of data in one column:

Pine-forest-water
Pine-apple-ocean
Pine-current-ocean
Range-current-ocean
Wander-apple-current

In this example I want the column to identify if any of the cells have these words/phrases- 'Range', 'Wander' and 'water' and automatically highlight the cell red.
In the actual thing I'll probably have 10+ codes I need the data to recognize so I need to be able to add to it.
I spent like 4 hours trying to figure this out and only got it to partially work.

Please post a screenshot with example data as the description like 5 rows of data in one column is confusing. A screenshot of a view with the sample data would be very helpful

Done. I want the code to recognize specific words and flag them all as the same colour.

You add additional OR ( || ) as you deem necessary. Let me know if you have any questions

Try the following and see if that works for you
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if((indexOf(toUpperCase(@currentField), 'WATER' )>-1) || (indexOf(toUpperCase(@currentField), 'RANGE' )>-1) || (indexOf(toUpperCase(@currentField), 'WANDER' )>-1), 'Red', '')",
    "font-size": "1.5em",
    "color" :"black"
  }
}



Visit this link for more info about json expressions used in this sample

Hi, thanks for this. For some reason when I enter the last two sections (font size and color) it states that formatting is invalid. I've tripled checked every space, bracket and comma. It just turns all the data white. I've added a photo of the code I current have. But with this one I'd have to enter every variation. Whereas I just want it to be able to flag those specific words.

There must be something not right in the JSON. Try using  OR clause like (condition1) || (condition2). Review my sample json.
